# Can't reach Raspberry Pi from a specific computer

Tags: raspberry-pi, connectivity, local-network

I've an issue connecting with my raspberry from a specific computer on home network.
Raspberry is connected on WiFi and my computer is connected on LAN.
The issue occurs only on the actual raspberry IP that is a static IP (192.168.1.3. This is correctly reached from every other device in the home network.
If I change the IP assigned to raspi it becomes reachable from my computer but I don't know why.

I've tried deleting DNS cache from the computer and checking Firewall rules but nothing found. I've also checked raspi to see if there are rules blocking the connection but nothing found here too.

Could you please help me understanding why this is happening? I would like to keep the actual IP assigned to the raspi.

Thank you

Comment: There’s a Raspberry Pi site on the [SE] network, which might be of help: [raspberrypi.SE].

Comment: You can probably just as easily use `mDNS`. If the RasPi has hostname `simon`, you can use `simon.local` instead of an IP address to access it from other machines.

Comment: @MarkSetchell actually I use the hostname that is resolved in the addres 192.168.1.3 but then I get "Request Timed out!", only from a specific computer